# "I being at office means her being at home." is it valid?

Tags: sentence-construction

I just read a sentence in my physics books:

> **Negative particles coming out of the negative terminal** corresponds to **positive particles coming out of the positive terminal.**

Can I use the same pattern and make a sentence:

> **I being at work** means **my wife being at home** as at least one person must always be at home to take care of our sick child.

Is the sentence valid?

I wonder if you would give me other examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of a participial clause cannot be a nominative pronoun. It should be accusative or in formal English genitive:

> **Me/my** being at work means **my wife/my wife's** being at home

Comment: Not even at the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: Not even at the beginning of a sentence.